# Deploying a web app via TFS2010 only copies certain folders, not all folders, to our development server

Tags: xaml, tfs, web-deployment, tfsbuild

My company uses TFS 2010 to deploy our web apps from our local environment to our development environment.  Here's the compiled output in my local directory for one of our vended web apps, ProGet, (http://inedo.com/proget/overview) in question that isn't deploying correctly.  I expect all of what I see below to deploy to our development server:

[image]

Here's my `.xaml` build file:

[image]
[image]

Finally, here's my solution in Visual Studio:

[image]

When I queue the build, this is what's built out to our development server - notice it's missing a bunch of files/folders, but it does include "Resources" and "bin" and `web.config`:

[image]

This app is a vended application, ProGet, an already developed corporate Nuget repository that we purchased a source code license for.  Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Here's a screenshot of my local IIS and the window to the right is a result of right clicking the website and choosing "Explore".  Notice the `*.cs` files.  Weird they don't compile down.

[image]

Comment: Well your screenshot includes .cs and .csproj files.  I wouldn't expect a build to output/deploy those; instead it should be deploying the binaries/assemblies only (not the source files).

Comment: @DylanSmith It's a different approach than what I'm used to... the product ProGet is a web based product yet has no cshtml, aspx, html, etc. files.  They're all C# (.cs).  From what the rep told me, the pages are basically created at runtime.  The app works on my localhost... maybe that's why it's only deploying those two folders, is because everything is .cs so it just compiles it down to a DLL into the bin??  But, when I build locally, the above screenshot is what I get as a compiled result

Comment: @DylanSmith Check out the screenshot I added - it's of my local IIS website and choosing "Explore" to explore the contents...

Answer (score 1):

The Default Build Template (DefaultTemplate.xaml) should output the same files you get when you compile locally.

However, from your screenshots it looks like you are using a custom build template xxxx_DeploymentProcess.xaml that is obviously doing something different with how it outputs the build files.  There is no way for us (stackoverflow community) to know what your custom build process is doing.

You could try switching back to the default template, and we'd be able to help you then.  But, there's a good chance that you are using a custom build template for a reason, and you might not want to eliminate it before you know what it's doing.

Comment: Yes, definitely.  I figured with a custom build template SOF wouldn't be able to provide much assistance, but it was a shot in the dark, given my screen shots of the XAML UI.

Comment: My TFS admin said the only difference between our custom template and the DefaultTemplate was that our custom template just "Xcopied" from the TFS drop location to the Dev share.  That's the only difference... when I build locally, I check the IIS directory and I get a ton more folders/etc. - look at the updated post - but TFS only builds out the bin and Resources folder...

Comment: Could it be the way the Visual Studio solution is set up (the solution structure)?

Comment: TFSBuild (and Visual Studio build) by default only output the binaries.  And TFS Build by default only copies the build outputs to the drop folder.  If you want to change this behaviour you have to customize the build.